# Configuring implicits in Scala

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit

I have typeclass:

```
trait ProcessorTo[T]{
    def process(s: String): T
}
```

and its implementation

```
class DefaultProcessor extends ProcessorTo[String]{
    def process(s: String): String = s
}
trait DefaultProcessorSupport{
    implicit val p: Processor[String] = new DefaultProcessor
}
```

To make it available for using I created

```
object ApplicationContext
    extends DefaultProcessorSupport
    with //Some other typeclasses
```

But now I have to add a processor which performs some DataBase - read. The DB URL etc are placed in condifguration file that is ***available only a runtime***. For now I did the following.

```
class DbProcessor extends ProcessorTo[Int]{
   private var config: Config = _
   def start(config: Config) = //set the configuration, open connections etc
   //Other implementation
}

object ApplicationContext{
    implicit val p: ProcessorTo[Int] = new DbProcessor
    def configure(config: Config) = p.asInstanceOf[DbProcessor].start(config)
}
```

It works for me, but I'm not sure about this technique. Looks strange for me a little bit. Is it a bad practice? If so, what would be a good solution?

Comment: Why not require that any method which wants to do processing will have an `implicit ev: Processor[T]`? What is this `ApplicationContext` object?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov `ApplicationContext` object contains typeclasses needed to be imported.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Even if I require `implict ev: Processor[T]`, I need to configure the `DbProcessor` anyway.

Comment: Ok, do you have to use an object to place all these implicits there? I'd separate these concerns out and have the outmost top place create an instance of the right processor I need.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov The reason I put all these implicits there was the following: I wanted to generify my processing engine which using some of these implicits and to modify its behavior just import the configured application context. So I abstraced away constructurs and configuration of the specific implicit in my application.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Is that kind of bad-practice in Scala?

Comment: I wouldn't say bad practice, it just hides things which are non obvious. When people will want to know how the "DbProcessor" gets initialized and where it's configuration happens, they'll need to search for it in a non trivial location. I'd consider moving all bootstrapping like this as high as possible, perhaps in Main even.

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit confused by the requirements as `DbProcessor` is missing the process implementation(???) and trait `ProcessorTo[T]` is missing start method which is defined in `DbProcessor`. So, I will assume the following while answering: the type class has both `process` and `start` methods

Define a type class:

```
  trait ProcessorTo[T]{
    def start(config: Config): Unit
    def process(s: String): T
  }
```

Provide implementations for the type class in the companion objects:

```
object ProcessorTo {
  implicit object DbProcessor extends ProcessorTo[Int] {
    override def start(config: Config): Unit = ???
    override def process(s: String): Int = ???
  }

  implicit object DefaultProcessor extends ProcessorTo[String] {
    override def start(config: Config): Unit = ???
    override def process(s: String): String = s
  }
}
```

and use it in your `ApplicationContext` as follows:

```
  object ApplicationContext {
    def configure[T](config: Config)(implicit ev: ProcessorTo[T]) = ev.start(config)
  }
```

This is a nice blog post about Type Classes: http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/06/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-12-type-classes.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see why you need `start`. If your implicit `DbProcessor` has a dependency, why not make it an explicit dependency via constructor? I mean something like this:

```
class DbConfig(val settings: Map[String, Object]) {}

class DbProcessor(config: DbConfig) extends ProcessorTo[Int] {

  // here goes actual configuration of the processor using config
  private val mappings: Map[String, Int] = config.settings("DbProcessor").asInstanceOf[Map[String, Int]]

  override def process(s: String): Int = mappings.getOrElse(s, -1)
}


object ApplicationContext {
  // first create config then pass it explicitly
  val config = new DbConfig(Map[String, Object]("DbProcessor" -> Map("1" -> 123)))
  implicit val p: ProcessorTo[Int] = new DbProcessor(config)
}
```

Or if you like Cake pattern, you can do something like this:

```
trait DbConfig {
  def getMappings(): Map[String, Int]
}

class DbProcessor(config: DbConfig) extends ProcessorTo[Int] {
  // here goes actual configuration of the processor using config
  private val mappings: Map[String, Int] = config.getMappings()

  override def process(s: String): Int = mappings.getOrElse(s, -1)
}

trait DbProcessorSupport {
  self: DbConfig =>
  implicit val dbProcessor: ProcessorTo[Int] = new DbProcessor(self)
}

object ApplicationContext extends DbConfig with DbProcessorSupport {
  override def getMappings(): Map[String, Int] = Map("1" -> 123)
}
```

So the only thing you do in your `ApplicationContext` is providing actual implementation of the `DbConfig` trait.